# Deeplink from bot to tab in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am currently working on a bot specifically targeting Teams. Search feature in this bot returns around 200-500 results. Even though i have integrated refines to narrow down search results, i still have to show around 50-100 records under a refined label. I am trying to avoid showing 100+ records as Carousel or list view in bot. so, I thought of integrating tab with bot and share a [deeplink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deep-links) to tab where user can see complete search result in a data table (jquery). 
I am unable to figure out two things on this approach and need help.

1. Tab content might be hosted in a different domain and needs authorization. How do I pass authorization info to Content url without asking user to login?
2. How do i pass custom parameters  while creating a deep link to tab and read custom data in a tab? For example, userID, accessToken.

Note: I am using AzureADV1 token with Adal.Net for Bot authentication, and storing token cache in a persistent storage.

I appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include a "context" parameter in your [static tab deeplink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deep-links#generating-a-deep-link-to-your-tab), similar to the configurable tab deeplink. If you include a "subEntityId" property in this context, you can get the value inside your static tab by calling getContext(). Then you can render a filtered results based on this sub-entity id.

Comment: sorry for the delay in responding. I haven't tried your suggestion but this should work for sure. Even this article gives the same info, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/tabs/tabs-context